# Solve problem with Venn's diagram, intersection of set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In a class there are 50% students study English, 30% study Hindi, 25% study foreign language, 10% study english with foreign language, find the percentage of students who study Hindi with foreign language, if no one studies all the three subjects at a time

I already do the intersection of the diagram, but I can't get the answer!

What I was able to infer:

People who only study Hindi + who no study nothing = 0.35

no_lang + only_hindi = 0.35

There's a solution?

Comment: You have **seven** unknowns (three single-language, three double-language, and one no-language), which are all non-negative percentages.  However you only have **five** simultaneous equations.

Comment: I was trying to find another equation, maybe there isn't then...

Comment: They told me that there's a solution if a fixed a total number of students. How is it? @GrahamKemp

Comment: So rather than percentage values, then you will have equations with natural-number-valued variables.  It might help, depending on the count.